# Order by then Group By in Mysql with Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table one contains the user information while other contains the user's device token and device type etc.

**tbl_user**

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | username | is_active |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 15 | UserA    | 1         | 
| 62 | UserB    | 1         | 
+----+----------+------------
```

**tbl_user_token**

```
+----------+---------+--------------+
| table_id | user_id | device_token |
+----------+---------+--------------+
| 1        | 15      | XXXXXXXXX    |
| 2        | 15      | XXXXXXXXX    |
| 3        | 15      | XXXXXXXXX    |
| 4        | 62      | XXXXXXXXX    |
| 5        | 62      | XXXXXXXXX    |
| 6        | 62      | XXXXXXXXX    |
+----------+---------+--------------+
```

So now i want to fetch the latest record from tbl_user_token
in above case it should be

```
+---+----+-----------+
| 3 | 15 | XXXXXXXXX |
| 6 | 62 | XXXXXXXXX | 
+---+----+-----------+
```

So far i have done below:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_user tu 
join tbl_user_token tut 
on tut.user_id = tu.id  
where tu.id in (15,62) and tu.is_active=1
group by tut.user_id
```

But it does not fetch the latest record.

Note:  My question is different then the suggested question because answers on that question focus on how to fetch max value records from single table. But there is no information about what to do if need to use join with another table and find latest records.

I have to add criteria in other table (i.e. with tbl_user) table.

Comment: The query should work.

Comment: Aren't all of the existing `User Id`s either 15 or 62?

Comment: do you want to fetch latest record with this query ?

Comment: No, my question is different. Because i need to add additional condition in my tbl_user table (like fetch only those users which are active etc.)

Comment: No, your question is not different, since it does not describe any additional criteria you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: on your suggested question, they are finding records only with in 1 table. While i have to add additional condition with first table. like SELECT * FROM tbl_user tu 
join tbl_user_token tut 
on tut.user_id = tu.id  
where tu.id in (15,62) and tu.status = 1
group by tut.user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your expected output, you don't need to join with tbl_user table.

You can find the latest table_id from each user_id and then join it with original table to get the required result.

Try this:

```
select t1.*
from tbl_user_token t1
join (
    select user_id, max(table_id) table_id
    from tbl_user_token
    where user_id in (15, 62)
    group by user_id
    ) t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    and t1.table_id = t2.table_id
```

Another method is using a left self join:

```
select t1.*
from tbl_user_token t1
left join tbl_user_token t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    and t1.table_id < t2.table_id
where t2.user_id is null
    and t1.user_id in (15, 62)
```

#### EDIT:

If you want to join the tbl_user, try this:

```
select t1.*, tu.*
from tbl_user_token t1
join (
    select user_id,
        max(table_id) table_id
    from tbl_user_token
    where user_id in (15, 62)
    group by user_id
    ) t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    and t1.table_id = t2.table_id
join tbl_user tu on t1.user_id = tu.id
```

For left join alternative, try this:

```
select t1.*, tu.*
from tbl_user_token t1
left join tbl_user_token t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    and t1.table_id < t2.table_id
join tbl_user tu on t1.user_id = tu.id
where t2.user_id is null
    and t1.user_id in (15, 62)
```

Comment: While I'm a great fan of the second method (it *is* called the strawberry query after all ;-)  ), it scales so poorly in relation to the first that I really wouldn't bother with it anymore.

Comment: @Strawberry - Well it depends. See this post by Bill Karwin showing analysis and comparison of the two method and proving the second one is way faster. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group/1313293#1313293

Comment: I'm very suspicious of that result. I'll try to replicate later, but I suspect that either there was some query caching going on or things were very different back in 2009.

Comment: @GurV, thanks for your answer. But what if i want to use join with tbl_user table as i have to add addition condition in query.

Comment: @DS9 - Added an update to the answer. Please check

Comment: Thank you so much. Its worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a row number group by `user_id` and in the descending order of `table_id`. Then select the rows with row number 1.

**Query**

```
select t1.`table_id`, t1.`user_id`, t1.`device_token` from 
(
    select `table_id`, `user_id`, `device_token`, 
    (
        case `user_id` when @A 
        then @R := @R + 1 
        else @R := 1 and @A := `user_id` end 
    ) as `rn`
    from `tbl_user_token` t, 
    (select @R := 0, @A := '') r 
    order by `user_id`, `table_id` desc 
)t1 
where t1.`rn` = 1
order by t1.`table_id`;
```

Sql Fiddle demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8dbd04/2)